# How do I print with the screen stylesheet?

Tags: browser, printing

A number of websites that I use have really bad stylesheets for the print media, but their screen stylesheets are quite good.

Is there any way to tell my browser to ignore the print stylesheet and just print with the screen stylesheet?

I’d also like to do this when I want to show clients the difference between the two.

Comment: If websites in question are of third-parties, maybe you could try Chrome's Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I), then right-click on node/element(the print stylesheet in this case) and select `Delete This Node`.

Comment: It is a duplicate!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode/

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but if on Firefox, you're merely annoyed that all the links are attached with their full URLs on the print preview **_(whoever thought this is a great idea needs to `die (http://www.have-an-agonizingly-slow-and-painful-death!!!.com)`)_** just open _Inspect Element (Dev Tools)_, go to _Style Editor_, use the handy _@media rules_ listing on the right side to find the stylesheet with `print` styles then remove all the `print` rules applied on `a[href]`. Then launch the Print Preview again.

Comment: @vy32 Please consider changing the accepted answer to [dj rock's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1328256/280695). That is the easiest way now.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using Chrome Developer Tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) is the only thing I have found that works.

1. Search for all instances of `media="screen"` and delete that attribute.
2. Then search for `media="print"` and delete that whole link.
3. Then try printing.

This generally gives me the page with screen styling.

If you really just want to disable print styles, you can install the Web Developer extension (I think there is a version for Firefox and Chrome). It has a button to disable print styles. However, it does not extend the "screen" style to print, so most of the time it does not work the way you hope it will.

Comment: Thanks. That's a great solution. Depressing, but great. The main website that I'm having a problem with is Wired, which for some reason prints horribly but looks great on the screen.

Comment: I need a plugin that does this.

Comment: @vy32 that is not a bad idea at all. I had been wanting to play with Chrome extensions for a while now. Over the holidays I finally had a couple hours. So here is PrintScreen, a little button that you click when a page has custom print/screen css media selectors. [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/printscreen/jmhipjpegbhhmhneoogigjgfmekglogf)

Comment: the PrintScreen button doesn't work so well???

Comment: Not terribly surprising, but I will say it worked on the websites I tested and on the test pages I created. That said, it is open source and on github [https://github.com/HurricaneJames/PrintScreen](https://github.com/HurricaneJames/PrintScreen), if you have a specific example of something not working please open an issue there and I can follow up with you. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: On my copy of Chrome the print page is not coming up at all. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I suspect this is a user experience issue. Normally I put more focus on user experience, but this time I was just playing around with new techniques and systems, and failed to pay attention. After clicking the PS button you need to click print the normal way. You are right, it would make more sense if I had the extension call the print directly. If I have time this week I will try to update the extension to go straight to the print screen as it really should. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work on later chrome versions.

Comment: Just tested in Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 and it works fine.

Comment: I think the problem may be due to an old user experience saying: "If the user cannot find it, the function is not there!" In that light, I just updated the extension to automatically open the print window after it was clicked. I suspect that clicking a button with apparently no effect has caused too much confusion. Also, be sure to tell chrome to print background images/colors, or the page will often look wrong. Updated Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/printscreen/jmhipjpegbhhmhneoogigjgfmekglogf

Comment: Some sites have no media=print css and instead rely on Javascript. Turning off JS worked for me. Settings / Advanced / Content.

Comment: I know it's been a long time since you posted this and I'm not sure if you're still supporting this extension or not, but the links to find the extension on the Chrome store are dead. :( Both the ones in the comments here and the one on the linked GitHub page (though the GitHub link itself works fine.)

Comment: For others who may be looking, there's an extension called FireShot that can capture a webpage's screen rendering and then lets you print it, save to PDF, or save to an image. However, if you save to PDF, it is not divided into pages. I just used this to print out a webpage with terrible print CSS, since the links in the comments here aren't currently working.

Answer (score 28):

I [found an easy way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode/) in **Chrome**.

- Open Developer Tools
- Vertical ellipsis menu (⋮)
- Show console drawer (<kbd>Esc</kbd>)
- Vertical ellipsis menu (⋮)
- Rendering
- Emulate CSS media type: screen.

Now try to print. It will pick the screen CSS instead of Print CSS.

Comment: More specifically on the current Chrome: Open developer tools. Top right 3-dot menu > More tools > Rendering. Scroll down to Emulate CSS Media.

Comment: Now is there really no way to simplify invoking this.

Comment: This is a copy of \@kitchin's 2015 answer to this question ([three years prior to this one](https://superuser.com/a/922735/241800)). If you wanted their answer to include the specific instructions you should have put forward an edit to it (much like @glenviewjeff put to yours, for some reason, adding the same link..)

Comment: Where is it in Chrome of 2023?

Answer (score 17):

There is a new method to directly choose the media emulation in Developer Tools, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode/

Comment: This works.  Follow the instructions and select the "screen" media type.  Then when you print it will use "screen"

Comment: As software evolves, so should stackexchange answers—this one should be the selected answer.

Comment: This was the only method that worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Leo had a [good idea](https://superuser.com/a/867609/581640) there, but it doesn't quite do what [James said](https://superuser.com/a/478268/129262): it should be

```
$('*[media="screen"]').attr('media', '');$('*[media="print"]').remove();
```

Hint: save the following as a bookmarklet for easy use:

```
javascript:var%20el=document.createElement('script');el.type="text/javascript";el.src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js";document.body.appendChild(el);setTimeout(function(){$('*[media="screen"]').attr('media','');$('*[media="print"]').remove();},%202000)
```

This preloads jQuery and waits 2secs for it to finish, but if this wait isn't enough, just run it again, jQuery should have been loaded in the meantime.

Answer (score 4):

1. Do anything [James said](https://superuser.com/a/478268/129262) ;)

   You can check the output opening the Chrome Developer Tools settings (right bottom corner) and select in "Overrides" the option "Emulate CSS media print"-view. By toggling this option you can compare print and screen view. Have fun!
2. Install this addon:
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/print-background-colors/gjecpgdgnlanljjdacjdeadjkocnnamk

Now background-images and colors are printed as well.

Bug: Doesn't work with CSS sprites.

EDIT: Chrome has changed the print view in 2014 I think so you do not need to use the linked addon anymore.

Comment: Using Chrome Developer Tools to set "Emulate CSS media" to "screen" is the only answer that works.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem with a website that had a single CSS file using `@media print` and `@media screen`, so the solution to disable the separate print CSS file didn't work for me. While I could certainly edit the CSS and comment out the print block while viewing the page, those changes didn't carry over to the print preview.

The solution I found was the Print Edit extension for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-edit/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/print-edit/olnblpmehglpcallpnbgmikjblmkopia?hl=en-US). It lets you edit the page immediately before printing, and includes a simple button to use the Web Style (`@media screen`) for the page.

I did have to change the scale I was printing at slightly, since the print surface is roughly a 17:22 ratio while my browser is roughly 16:9, so some of the stuff on the page was getting a bit crowded horizontally. I also had to enable printing the background colors & images separately

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  I had already spent 10 minutes changing a sites text to purple as my printer had run out of ink.  Using this solution I could install the extension, press the web style button and wallah it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes web sites use CSS to specify that [different styles](https://benfrain.com/create-print-styles-using-css3-media-queries/) should be used on-screen and when printing.  This is often good, but it can also be confusing and problematic. Inspect the source code of the page and look for something like:

```
@media print {
  *:after {
    color: #000 !important;
    background: transparent !important;
  }
```

One reason this problem is common is that web sites using the popular [Bootstrap framework](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/) use the ubiquitous [bootstrap.min.css](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css) file, which contains the CSS style above.

The key thing to look for is `@media print`. Web sites often have complex structures and it may help to save the page locally and inspect it with a recursive text-searching tool.

When you think you've found the spot in the CSS code, you can modify the page directly in your browser by using its developer features. (In Chrome you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to launch them.)

Search for the CSS code and just remove or invalidate the rows causing the problem. Verify that the operation worked by using "Print preview".

Answer (score 0):

Install Greasemonkey addon and use the script  given below.

I modified a script I found here http://www.netsi.dk/wordpress/index.php/2011/07/07/printing-html-pages-make-screen-and-print-appear-the-same/

I changed "screen" to "print" at the end (I have no idea about jQuery, so don't ask me any questions) so that in effect it sends the screen version to the printer. When printing to pdf, (using Foxit or Nitro Pdf printers), I set the page type to Tabloid Extra in landscape mode so the pdf size matches the screen size more or less. Enjoy! Remember, I don't know a thing about programming, so the credit goes to the original author.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Show print version (A Cross Browser Example) (showPrintVersion.user.js)
// @namespace    netsi
// @match http://*/*
// @author       Sten Hougaard
// @description  Simply add #print to the URL. As descriped in my blog post (goo.gl/MEizV) this will activate any media=print stylesheets so that you can see the print version without printing
// ==/UserScript==

// a function that loads jQuery and calls a callback function when jQuery has finished loading
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

// the guts of this userscript
function main() {
  var bPrint = (window.location.toString().indexOf('#print')!=-1);  
  if (bPrint) {
    // The user wants to print this page
    jQuery('link[media*="screen"]').attr('media', 'all'); // Enable the screen styling for all media types, including screen.
    jQuery('link[media*="print"]').remove(); // remove any styling related to print
  }
}

// load jQuery and execute the main function
addJQuery(main);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to enable `"Print background (colors & images)"` option in `Page Setup` and check how it looks in `Print Preview` (It's for FF).

Comment: Does not have the desired result. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Similar to James - use "Sources" tab in Chrome Developer tools, and *replace* all instances of `media print` with `media speech`.  Thus all the css changes to hide navbars etc will not be applied when printing (but will be applied when text-to-speech is used)

This may be doable with JQuery as above.

This is useful as I am using the CDN of css so customisation is right out

Answer (score -2):

There is a great tool for that on Mac.

Install Paparazzi 
=> copy URL to Paparazzi
=> Save image as => PDF

(in PDF exports, even the Text ist selectable, it's not just an "image")

https://derailer.org/paparazzi/screenshots

enjoy :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this program makes a bitmap print, which means that the fonts are rasterized. It's not what I want.